# Why would Cells(x,y).Value return empty for non-empty cells in Excel VBA?

Tags: vba, excel

I have an Excel VBA function. In a loop, I use `Cells(x,y).Value` to return the value of certain cells. But sometimes that returns empty, even the cell is not empty.

One example in my worksheet is `Cells(11,4).Value`. So I placed both `Cells(11,4)` and `Cells(11,4).Value` in Watches.

In Watches, drilling down into `Cells(11,4)` shows **Text** to be "42.71%", and **Value2** to be "0.42708218178176", which is what I would expect.

But also in Watches, `Cells(11,4).Value` still shows "Empty".

Adding to the mystery, if I delete another watch, then `Cells(11,4).Value` will suddenly now be populated!

[image]

The obvious questions are:

- Why?
- What can I do to stop `Cells(11,4).Value` returning Empty?

**Edited to add:**
The VBA is lengthy and irrelevant (i.e. if I strip it back to a single line, I get the same result).

More relevant is the formula contained in cell D11 (the cell I'm interested in). It's this:
=`(((D8+D9)/D5)^(1/(DATEDIF(D3,IF(D6>0,D6,LOOKUP(2,1/(D18:D9998<>""),$B18:$B9998)),"d")/365.25))-1)`

That `IF` function returns two possible values: `D6` or `LOOKUP(2,1/(D18:D9998<>""),$B18:$B9998)`. (The latter is intended to get the value from column B for the last value in column D.)

If I put a value in `D6` (so the `IF` statement doesn't do the LOOKUP), then `Cells.Value` returns the correct result. If there's no value in `D6`, and the `IF` statement returns the `LOOKUP` formula, then `Cells.Value` will return `Empty`.

Comment: Can you add a sample of the excel, and the VBA function ?

Comment: Then the obvious question would be: Does the Lookup actually return anything?

Comment: What if you change the watch to `ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(11, 4)`?  Not sure if a watch continues to look at the initial `Activesheet` as you change sheets.

Answer (score 0):

I've answered my second question, "how do I stop Cells(11,4).Value returning Empty?".

If I change

`LOOKUP(2,1/(D18:D9998<>""),$B18:$B9998)`

to

`LOOKUP(2,1/(D18:D999<>""),$B18:$B999)`

Then the problem goes away. (There's no data in rows 1000-10000, by the way. I just put in a very large number to be sure the formula would still work in the future.)

I haven't yet answered my first question: "why?". Bug? Limitation? Something else?

Comment: You need to clarify what the `Lookup` function is doing in both scenarios. Does it return a value? An error? How do you expect us to answer your question with only knowing half of what's going on?

Comment: @Inarion - in both scenarios the `Lookup` function returns exactly the same result.  As I said, there's no data in rows 1000-10000, so changing the size of the lookup won't make any difference. That's what's confusing.

Comment: It seems to me the issue is too complex (especially when only seen remotely and with limited information). What I'd try to do is to strip away parts of the surroundings (data, parts of the formula, whatever else there is) until the problem stops occuring. Then you've got yourself a fine [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that the experts (and aspiring experts) here can examine.

Comment: I'm guessing, but I think the problem is caused by an issue to do with the order in which functions are calculated. For some reason, when the `LOOKUP` function has many rows, it's calculated after my function, and so my function returns no value. That problem doesn't actually affect my worksheet, because as soon as the `LOOKUP` function is calculated, Excel goes back to my VBA function and runs it again. So looking at the Worksheet, you wouldn't know it was running twice. It's only when you add breakpoints that you see it happening and get confused, as I did.